# ERROR: Internal Python error in the inspect module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was assigned in a edx python course to create a program that print out the longest substring that is in alphabetical order from a given string. I have written my code, but when i ran it I got "ERROR: Internal Python error in the inspect module.". I don't understand why. If someone could help me figure it out it would be great. This is the code:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
start=0
temp=0
while start<len(s):
    initial=start
    while True:
        if ord(s[start])<=ord(s[start+1]):
            start+=1
        else:
            start+=1
            if len(s[initial:start])>temp:
                sub=s[initial:start]
                temp=len(sub)
            break    
print sub
```

and this is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yoav\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.4.3105.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 776, in structured_traceback
    records = _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, context, tb_offset)
  File "C:\Users\Yoav\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.4.3105.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 230, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Yoav\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.4.3105.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 267, in _fixed_getinnerframes
    if rname == '<ipython console>' or rname.endswith('<string>'):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
ERROR: Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.


Unfortunately, your original traceback can not be constructed.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the code mostly works, however when you call break, it only breaks out of the else block, and continues to run the while, with a value for start that is greater than the max index for s.

Try putting this code in a function, and using a return when you find the correct substring

Good luck!

```
def sub_finder(s):

start=0
temp=0
while start<len(s):
    initial=start
    while True:
        if (start < len(s) - 1):
            if ord(s[start])<=ord(s[start+1]):
                start+=1
            else:
                start+=1
                if len(s[initial:start])>temp:
                    sub=s[initial:start]
                    temp=len(sub)
                break
        else:
            start+=1
            if len(s[initial:start])>temp:
                sub=s[initial:start]
                temp=len(sub)
            return sub

test = 'abcdaabcdefgaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbcdefg'
print sub_finder(test)
```

whoops, try this on for size.

Comment: the code doesn't work. I checked it for s = 'azcbobobegghakl' (for which it should print 'beggh', and it printed 'az'

Comment: but i still don't understand why i need the "start<len(s)-1" and not just "start<len(s)"

Comment: You're checking the indexes start and start+1. During the last iteration, start will be equal to len(s), and start+1 will be one greater than len(s). If you use "start<len(s)" you will get an index out of range error